# Cordova Camera Fails

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I keep getting the following error whenever I try to open up my Android camera with Cordova Camera:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ionicApp144916/cache/.Pic.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`

The strange thing is that it works fine when I run ionic run android.  It seems like this is an old bug that was supposed to be fixed a year ago - Many of the solutions online involve updated the version of cordova camera or the android platform.  I have done this and it still doesn't work.  Has anyone ever resolved this problem before?

Comment: any solution did you get for this?